# Save excel file from outlook mail that is in the message body

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

How do i save an excel attachment that is in the message body instead where attachments usually am? ( under the recipient)

a sample of what it look like
[image]

when it should be like this

[image]

i am using

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("test") #6 = Inbox (without mails from the subfolder)
        messages = inbox.Items
        for item in messages:
                mail=item
                attachments = mail.Attachments
                attachment = attachments.Item(1)
                for attachment in mail.Attachments:
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(rootpath,str(attachment)))
```

but an error informing me that there are no attachments will be shown

Note that the sender is a bot from an outside party, i am not able to alter the way it sends the attachment

Answer (score 0):

The attachment icon is shown inside the message body only if you are composing a message in the RTF format.